# Seeking Open Source alternatives to Google's StreetView engine?

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, software-recommendations

I am looking to create an open source javascript app using either Leaflet or OpenLayers.

Is there any way to implement panoramic views (similar to Google's StreetView) into either of these, or any other open API?

My panoramic views would be custom made from personal photos so I will not need to grab panoramic images from an existing service.

I understand that it is possible to incorporate Google StreetView into non-Google apps, but is there anything out there that would give me similar functionality without using any Google API?

Answer (score 6):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

The OpenView Project is an open source panoramic open source project.

*Interactive panoramas of people instead of asphalt.*

openviewproject.org (dead expired link)

(looks like the project has slowed down.)

But you can use Streetview/Photosynth API's with your own panoramas which is a possible (but not open source route)

[Mapjack](http://www.mapjack.com/?pvxmWfyubFbE) is probably the best alternative to streetview (though not open source)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, it does not exist.

By the way, Google street view API provides also a way to [incorporate your own images](http://www.diy-streetview.org/2011/03/17/google-streetview-player-for-diy-streetviews/?utm_campaign=Google%20streetview%20player%20for%20DIY%20streetviews!&utm_medium=twitter&utm_source=twitter) it seems. That means you would be able to use it into an open-source app with you own photos but with a closed API!

Answer (score 2):

[Mapillary](https://www.mapillary.com/about)

> Anyone can join the community and collect street level photos by using simple tools like smartphones or action cameras.
>
> By connecting photos across time and users, we can create an immersive street-level photo view for people to virtually explore different places in the world. It could be a walk on a beach in Costa Rica, the streets of Tokyo or a drive through the Swedish countryside.
>
> We simply want to empower you to decide which streets, roads and hidden paths should be mapped, and when. There is no longer a need to wait for someone else to take street level photos for you.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenStreetCam](https://github.com/openstreetcam) project might be useful as it allows you to selfhost StreetView like service. It's not as polished and will require a lot of work to integrate into existing systems. Take a look at [the site](https://openstreetcam.org) to get a feel. It also have opensource apps for direct mobile uploads.

Another link you can check for already existing services around the world is this [list on HowlingPixel](https://howlingpixel.com/i-en/List_of_street_view_services).