# Incorporate Google Streetview into a Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, google

The person who asked the question at the link below way back in 2011 said, "I understand that it is possible to incorporate Google StreetView into non-Google apps".

Can anyone tell me how this is possible? I'd like to add street view functionality to my leaflet map.

[Open source alternatives to Google's StreetView engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14798/open-source-alternatives-to-googles-streetview-engine)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/ this is against the terms of service.

If you don't mind incurring the wrath of Google, take a look at the [StreetView API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview):

> **Street View Locations and Point-of-View (POV)**
>
> The StreetViewPanorama constructor also allows you to set the Street
>   View location and point of view using the StreetViewOptions parameter.
>   You may call setPosition() and setPov() on the object after
>   construction to change its location and POV.

You could use your Leaflet map to set the location for the panorama, perhaps by modifying the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple) (which uses Google Maps to set the location).

Comment: As always, you should check the license to verify that you're *allowed* to show a streetview image on a non-Google map. I've seen this done on Esri maps, but that doesn't mean it's legal

Comment: according to a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782223/3380951), it is against the terms. `Terms: cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms (d) No Use With Non-Google Maps. Customer will not use the Google Maps Core Services in a Customer Application that contains a non-Google map. For example, Customer will not (i) display Places listings on a non-Google map, or (ii) display Street View imagery and non-Google maps in the same Customer Application.`

Comment: @JeffXiao thanks, I updated the answer to mention this explicitly

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue of STREETVIEW I use leaflet library 
https://gist.github.com/crofty/2197042 google-Leaflet  and also build upon the previous review and I could also accomplish this. I hope they serve.

http://jsfiddle.net/ALL4k/

Answer (score 1):

Better use this plugin:

https://github.com/Zverik/leaflet-streetview

Instant Street view in the leaflet location given