# Using Google Streetview with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, google-street-view

I'm pretty new to leaflet and I'm trying to figure out how to use Google Streetview with Leaflet.

What I would like to have is the Google pegman in the right bottom of my map so that I can click and drag it to have the street view :

[image]

Can anyone provide me with an example of the Javascript/HTML code that allows to do this ?

Comment: This is valid question and [Incorporate Google Streetview into a Leaflet map](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70636/incorporate-google-streetview-into-a-leaflet-map) is not a duplicate. There is no function "setStreetView" in the Leaflet library - this is specific to the Google api.